# How to use MSYS with QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I found a very nice tutorial at: http://sproke.blogspot.com/2012/02/mapping-software-for-84.html, which has some "unix-like scripts", which should be use with QGIS. How can I copy and paste these scripts into MSYS?? Starting MSYS on my win-machine there is no menu-bar and strg+V doesn't work

PS. I search the qgi-manual for vers. 1.73, but found no info. any hints, links ??

Comment: (Not an answer, just tip) So what's your question?
Try to search for "copy paste best practices".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually a middle (mouse) click will paste into the msys window if that is what you are trying to do?

Comment: Darren, thank you very much. that was exactly what I was looking for, but could not find myself. thank you for help a newbie

Comment: Thanks Kurt; glad to help! If a response answers your question, you should click the 'checkmark' beside it to say so, and perhaps also give it an 'upvote' with the up arrow as well.

Comment: Darren, I have upvoted and clicked the checkmark. thanks again for your friendly help